# jQuery trigger excluding with .not()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want clicking on the img "tri" to hide the div "popu". But the img is a child of the div popu so i tried .not(). It didn't work. Note: Also I don't want div "textb" to trigger the hide.

### HTML

```
<div id="re" class="column"><div id="s" class="popu"><img class="tri" src="img/whtri.png"/>
    <div class="textb"><center style="font-size:14px;">Item Title</center>
        <span style="font-size:12px;">Description this is an item that is very good and i like it very much! I like 
            <span class="highl">More...</span>
        </span>
        <span style="">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JQuery

```
$("body").click(function (e) {
 if (!$(e.target).closest(".popu").length.not(".tri")) {
    $("#s").hide(200)
 }
});
```

Any Help Would Be Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.parent()`:

```
$('img.tri').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();    
});
```

or `.closest()`:

```
$('img.tri').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.popu').hide();    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2NXpu/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```
$('.tri').click(function(){
$('#s').hide();
});
```